# Django : get_context_data method from classview not working

Tags: django, django-views, django-templates

I want to make an application that uploads files to an azure blobstorage, with a part dedicated to the history of all uploaded files.

I used the post and get method of classview FormView and it works perfectly to upload the files.

Now I have to query the database/model to get the history to display it. So I think the best solution is to use the get_context_data method to pass the data to the template. However it doesn't work, no data are transferred and I can't target the problem.

Below is my classview and my html.

##### Views.py

```
class DocumentUpload(FormView) :
    model   = TblDocument
    template_name = 'documents/documents.html'
    form_class = FilesForm
    context_object_name = 'object_list'

    def get_context_data(self, *args, **kwargs):

        # Call the base implementation first to get a context
        context = super(DocumentUpload, self).get_context_data(*args, **kwargs)
        context['object_list'] = TblDocument.objects.all()

        return context

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        form = self.form_class()
        return render(request, self.template_name, {'form': form})

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        form = self.form_class(request.POST, request.FILES)
        files_selected = request.FILES.getlist('Filename') # create a list of files

        if form.is_valid():

            for file in files_selected :

                # DEFINE THE DATA OF THE FILE
                file = FileDefinitionBeforeUpload(file=file).file_information()

                # GET THE CONTENT OF THE FILE
                content = file.read()
                file_io =  BytesIO(content)

                # THE UPLOAD TO THE BLOB
                AzureBlobFile   = AzureBlob(filename= file.name)
                blob_client     = AzureBlobFile.blob_client()
                blob_client.upload_blob(data=file_io)

                user = self.request.session.get('user')

                newfile = TblDocument(  User                = user.get('email'), 
                                        Filename            = file.name, 
                                        Filenamebeforeindex = file.previous_name, 
                                        Sizefile            = file.size, 
                                        Format              = file.extension,
                                        # ID_Customer     = id_contrat, 
                                        Url                 = blob_client.url)
                newfile.save()

            else :

                form = FilesForm()
 
        return render(request, self.template_name, {'form': form})
```

##### html

```
<div class="upload-app">
     
    <div class="upload-in">
        <h2>Upload</h2>

        <form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            
            {% csrf_token %}
            {{ form.as_p }}

            <button type="submit" id="submitupload">Upload</button>
        </form>
    
        <div class="fileselect">
            <p>Selected files :</p>
                <div id="fileselect"></div>
        </div>     
    </div> 
    <div class="listfiles">

        <h2>Files Uploaded</h2>

        <table id="customers">
            <tr>
                <th>Filename</th>
                <th>Date</th>
                <th>Size</th>
            </tr>

            {% for file in object_list %}
            <tr>
                <td>{{ file.Filenamebeforeindex }}</td>
                <td>{{ file.Timestamp | date:'d.m.Y H:i'}}</td>
                <td>{{ file.Sizefile | filesizeformat}}</td>
            </tr>
            {% endfor %}

        </table>
</div>
```

Comment: You overwritten get method of FormView, delete it as it's automatically pass your form_class as form to template and will call get_context_data

Comment: As a rule of thumb: do *not* override `get` or `post` for a class-based view, except the simple `View`, which has no (useful) implementation for these methods.

Comment: Thank you, it works now before uploading by the post method. However, after uploading a file. the list disappear since it is overwrittent by the context of the form. Is it a way to change that ?